# Display data with an AngularJS ng-repeat, in a div, side by side

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an arraylist from which I need to get values where `isActive = true`, and to display the data in a `<div>` tag with the use of `ng-repeat`.

My problem is that I don't want to keep using `ng-repeat` every time, while fetching values in each `<div>` tag.

Is there any generic solution which will iterate only once, and I can see the value in `<div>`, side by side.  Please see this attempt:

[enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mg7l3muv4ll6avY6Hb4b)

I want to see a result like this:

[image]

Comment: Your link not working.

Comment: (http//plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2)   Sorry for that

Comment: Updated link in main question also.

Comment: So in your data model `isActive: true` will be only 1 value??

Comment: yes it will be always 1 value as true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your ng-repeat like below.
Whenever it get isActive true, it will create the div section for this.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="tempData in data">
      <div ng-if="tempData.isActive == true" >
        <div class="col-xs-12" >
            <div class="col-xs-4">Plan Type:</div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">{{tempData.plantype}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">Term:</div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">{{tempData.term}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">Rate:</div> 
            <div class="col-xs-8">{{tempData.rate}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
```